# Swing app is hanging when i call requestFocus() on a component

Tags: java, swing, textfield

My Swing application has two textfields. First Textfields has validation part and accepts only valid data. If we don't valid data, it will shows a dialog box on the top of that window. I am doing vaildation of first textfield only after calling requestFocus on textfield component. Now swing app is hanging at requestFocus() calling and dailog box is not appearing as i given invalid data. I have checked before that second field visible, displayabe, focusable or not. I have tried to understand how requestFocus() works. But i didn't get enough info. Do you have any idea when calling requestFocus() won't work.

Comment: See [*How to Use the Focus Subsystem*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification); ensure that your implementation of `verify()` has "no side effects."

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I think some recursion happens while validation. Try to do the validation on document. I would able to help if i can see some code.